# adding property to array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to learn and understand javascript.

what is wrong with the following code?

```
var d=[];
d[0]=document.createElement('div');
d[0].title=document.createElement('div');
d[0].appendChild(d[0].title);
```

I get this error:
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the name `title` is reserved. Try a different name.

Answer (score 2):

This line `d[0].appendChild(d[0].title);` is expecting an element to be appended to the div. Your simply appending a text node. Create another `div` (or whatever element you want) and append that.

Comment: Is there a way to create that div as a property of d[0]?

Comment: @user2799563 -- `d[0]` is a position in an array, that currently holds a div, use `d[1]`

Answer (score 0):

`.title` is an attribute of the element, which is a string.  When you try to append something to that attribute it is expecting a string.